Siddur Masok Midvash on cleansing our soul before Shabbos
I have heard from Rav Daniel Glatstein shlita (Shiur: Parshas Emor: The Mystical Dimensions of Shabbos - When They Arrive and How to Hold On To Them), that there is a concept that the six perakim of Tehillim (95-99 and 29), we recite on Kabbalos HaShabbos, are to clean ourselves from the "weekday-klipos", the impurity we got during the week. We don't want that on Shabbos, so these chapters are to cleanse ourselves from that.
These psalms purify and refine our souls in preparation for the holy Shabbos. We recite them to remove the klipos accumulated during the weekdays and to sanctify ourselves in the light of Shabbos.
Does anyone know where this section of Masok Midvash can be found (is it online? -EDIT: FOUND, THANKS TO YOREINU)
and why especially these six chapters are to "cleanse our souls for Shabbos"? What is so special about them? Please cite sources.

Partial answer-
Found it in the  Siddur Matok Midvash (תשפ”א)

very loosely translated - "And one starts to say these six chapters before all. Every chapter correspondence to one of the six weekdays. One should have in mind that with every chapter its everyday event [i don't know how to interpret "Dvar Yomo Beyomo" better], that he cuts and removes the "Klippot" that dominated and prevailed on that day, in the secret of the discourse of our lips [again, very unsure how to interpret "Sod Siach Siftoteinu]
The source is a sefer called תקוני שבת, although I don't know who that is and what the significance of these 6 Mizmorim are.
Found some infor about the tikkunei shabbat here

יצא לאור בשנת שע"ב בערך בקראקא ע"י ר' יהודה ב"ר דוד הכהן מהעיר בודון, לימים בודפסט. כדאי לעיין במאמרו של יצחק יוסף כהן, סדר קבלת שבת ופזמון לכה דודי, בתוך ספרו קורות ומקורות.


Thanks wonderful. Could you maybe provide the hebrew/english translation of the piece in masok midvash? I can’t read rashi script unfortunately

@Shmuel added a very unprofessional English translation. keep in mind that this is above most people's paygrade .

@Shmuel I am not certain about the Siddur, but in the Masok Midvash Zohar, whenever anything is printed in rashi script it mean that it is a kabbalistic explanation. More pshat, or applicable things are in regular script. I am assuming the Siddur follows suit

Fantastic, many thanks! Still wondering how these chapters correspond to day 1-6.
